# Javascript: Class Properties becoming undefined during Drag Events

Tags: javascript, class, draggable, addeventlistener

I'm pretty new with classes in Javascript and I've been stuck for a few days trying to understand why my properties are becoming undefined in all of my methods...

I was trying to replicate [this](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/drag.htm) into a class, but was unsuccessful since my properties are undefined every-time a method is called.

I could not find a similar issue on stackoverflow, but please link me if there is one as I'm probably not searching the correct question.

```
<div class="row" style="height: 800px;">
    <div class="col" id="container">
        <div class="card" style="width: 300px; border-top: solid 20px black;" id="dragcard">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
class DragEvents {

    dragCard = document.querySelector("#dragcard");
    container = document.querySelector("#container");

    currentX = 0;
    currentY = 0;
    initialX;
    initialY;

    constructor() {

        this.container.addEventListener("mousedown", this.dragStart, false);
        this.container.addEventListener("mouseup", this.dragEnd, false);
        this.container.addEventListener("mousemove", this.drag, false);

        console.log(this.currentX);//works, but I need this to work in my methods.
    }

    drag() {
        console.log("Drag");//fires
        console.log(this.currentX);//undefined
        console.log(this.currentY);//undefined
        console.log(this.initialX);//undefined
        console.log(this.initialY);//undefined
    }

    dragStart() {
        console.log("DragStart");//fires
    }

    dragEnd() {
        console.log("DragEnd");//fires
    }

}//End Class
var DragEvent = new DragEvents();
```

Comment: Also, some of them come up as "NAN" and when I console.log(typeof this.currentX); it says it's a "number".... so that was really puzzling too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common issue in webapp development, especially when you're trying to use instance methods as event handlers.

Normally, when you call something like

```
instance.method(foo);
```

The function `method` is called, with `this` pointing to `instance` and `foo` as the sole parameter. This is how most people expect this code to behave.

However, `instance.method` (without the invocation) is just a reference to a function. If you did:

```
const bar = instance.method;
bar(foo);
```

You would see different behavior. In this case, `bar` is called with `this` pointing to nothing and `foo` as the sole parameter. This is because the function is no longer bound to `instance` in the way it was when you called `instance.method(foo)`;

This is precisely what is happening when you call

```
this.container.addEventListener("mousedown", this.dragStart, false);
```

You pass in a reference to the function that `this.dragStart` points to, but the connection to your class is lost.

There are a number of ways around this. They all do the same thing, effectively, which is to bind the event handlers to an instance of your class:

**Arrow function expressions** 
You could use [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to bind the value of `this` to your class:

```
constructor() {
  this.container.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => this.dragStart(e), false);
  this.container.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => this.dragEnd(e), false);
  this.container.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => this.drag(e), false);
}
```

**bind method**
You could also use the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to explicitly bind `this` to the function reference

```
constructor() {
  this.container.addEventListener("mousedown", this.dragStart.bind(this), false);
  this.container.addEventListener("mouseup", this.dragEnd.bind(this), false);
  this.container.addEventListener("mousemove", this.drag.bind(this), false);
}
```

**ES6 method definition**
You can also change how you define your class methods so that the functions are bound to an instance of the class:

```
class DragEvents {

    /* ... */

    drag = () => { /* ... */ }

    dragStart = () => { /* ... */ }

    dragEnd = () => { /* ... */ }

}//End Class
```